# Can I delete <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" ..."/> when I upgrade to play-services-ads:17.0.0?

Tags: android

I upgrade Ads from 15.0.1 to 17.0.0

I have read the article https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/quick-start#update_your_androidmanifestxml

so I added `<meta-data  android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP" android:value="true"/>` to AndroidManifest.xml.

Can I delete both `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>` and `<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>` in my current AndroidManifest.xml

**Current AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<meta-data  android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP" android:value="true"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

**Current build.gradle**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
```

**Previous AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

**Previous build.gradle**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a different (unrelated) post pointing to play-services-basement. Out of curiousity, I added the ad dependency (same version as you) to my file, and opened the merged manifest view. If you don't know what that is, it's the manifest that includes components generated by dependencies. It's also color coded, so it's easy to notice this:

[image]

The version is automatically included by the play-services-basement dependency (which is added by the ad dependency automatically; you don't need to manually add it).

So to answer your question, you can delete it. It's automatically added to the XML file.